# WCF service relative uri without .svc

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a solution with 3 projects:

- MEProject.WCF.ServiceLayer (Service-Implementation)
- MEProject.WCF.HostConsole (Console Application which can host the service)
- MEProject.WCF.HostIIS (WCF Service Application)

My goal is that I can switch between the 2 projects without changing the uri (the endpoint configurations) in the client project. Well, the problem is, if I start the console application, the endpoints are

```
http://localhost:8080/MultipleEndpointService/FirstEndpoint
http://localhost:8080/MultipleEndpointService/SecondEndpoint
```

But if I start the WCF service application, the endpoints are

```
http://localhost:8080/MultipleEndpointService.svc/FirstEndpoint
http://localhost:8080/MultipleEndpointService.svc/SecondEndpoint
```

As you can see, the difference is the ".svc". Now my question: How can I tell the WCF service application to act like the console application and not to have the ".svc" in the uri?

Here is the code I use to get the multiple endpoints in the console application:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.ToList().ForEach(channelDispatcher =>
    {
        ChannelDispatcher dispatcher = channelDispatcher as ChannelDispatcher;
        if (dispatcher != null)
        {
            dispatcher.Endpoints.ToList().ForEach(endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new CallBackInstanceProvider(serviceDescription.ServiceType, InstanceCreator);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the WCF service application web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MEProject.Service.WCF.HostIIS.MultipleEndpointService">
    <endpoint name="FirstEndpoint" address="FirstEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MEProject.Service.WCF.ServiceLayer.IFirstEndpoint"/>
    <endpoint name="SecondEndpoint" address="SecondEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MEProject.Service.WCF.ServiceLayer.ISecondEndpoint"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/MultipleEndpointService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for running a WCF without the SVC extension you will need to use routing

for example i have a service named MultipleEndpointService.svc and i want to get the service like the following: 
.../MultipleEndpointService/FirstEndpoint

we can do it like this:
Global.asax:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MultipleEndpointService/FirstEndpoint", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MultipleEndpointService)));            

    }
}
```

MultipleEndpointService.svc.cs:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MultipleEndpointService : IMultipleEndpointService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Web.config (for IIS7):

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>

    <handlers>
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
    </handlers>             

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

[source](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/fileless-activation-of-wcf-service-in-net-4-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Try URL ReWriting :

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- Rewrite requests to /MultipleEndpointService.svc to /MultipleEndpointService -->
            <rule name="MultipleEndpointService" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="MultipleEndpointService.svc(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/MultipleEndpointService{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```